# Getting NPE in getparent() in Activitygroup

Tags: android

I'm new to android, this may be a simple question but I can't be able to find the answer for it. I'm using tabactivity while changing the activities the bottom tab's are missing.

I want tab's throughout the application. So for that, I did something like this in all the tab's (extends ActivityGroup):

```
public void replaceContentView(String id, Intent newIntent) {
    try {
        @SuppressWarnings("deprecation")
        View view = getLocalActivityManager().startActivity(id,
                newIntent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP))
                .getDecorView();
        this.setContentView(view);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

By clicking the button I want to change the view and tab's must be present so for that I did:

```
done.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

            Intent i = new Intent(v.getContext(), Woosuite_Feed.class);
            Woosuite_Feed feed = (Woosuite_Feed) getParent();//here i'm getting NPE 
            feed.replaceContentView("one", i);

        }
    });
```

But while calling parent activity I'm getting NPE exception, I searched for this, most of them saying it should be embedded child of your parent.

I don't know how to make embedded child, please someone guide me.

Here is my logcat:

```
12-20 15:30:16.774: E/AndroidRuntime(4690): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
12-20 15:30:16.774: E/AndroidRuntime(4690): java.lang.NullPointerException
12-20 15:30:16.774: E/AndroidRuntime(4690): at com.example.woosuite.Woosuite_Twiter_Feed_list$1.onClick(Woosuite_Twiter_Feed_list.java:76)
12-20 15:30:16.774: E/AndroidRuntime(4690): at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:4191)
12-20 15:30:16.774: E/AndroidRuntime(4690): at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:17229)
12-20 15:30:16.774: E/AndroidRuntime(4690): at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:615)
12-20 15:30:16.774: E/AndroidRuntime(4690): at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
12-20 15:30:16.774: E/AndroidRuntime(4690): at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
12-20 15:30:16.774: E/AndroidRuntime(4690): at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4960)
12-20 15:30:16.774: E/AndroidRuntime(4690): at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
12-20 15:30:16.774: E/AndroidRuntime(4690): at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
12-20 15:30:16.774: E/AndroidRuntime(4690): at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1038)
12-20 15:30:16.774: E/AndroidRuntime(4690): at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:805)
12-20 15:30:16.774: E/AndroidRuntime(4690): at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Comment: Please also copy the logcat of the NPE and the line of your code where the crash occurs. Thanks.

Comment: Hi please check my edits and logcat